# Is it possible to import only a part of a vue component?

Tags: vue.js

I'm coding a Vue app and want to know if it's possible to import only a part of a component.

For instance, i have a template and, inside this template,have a modal, how can i import this modal in another component? If possible...

I know that i can import the whole component but if i do so, is there a way to use only the modal?

I've looked in a lot of places but, they all teach how to import the component and not just part of it, if possible.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extract the modal as a new component and import it in the other components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not import only part of a Vue component. If you have a piece of the inner-component that you want to re-use (e.g. the "modal" that you are referring to), then you simply need to pull that piece of code out and create a new component with just the "modal" code. Then, you can use that code in both of your components.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answer, i actually thought about this possibility but I was wondering if i could try another approach...
Thanks again, upvoted both of you...

Comment: @GabrielSassaki => If this is the answer to your question, please mark it as the answer so that others in the future will be able to find it easier. Thank you!